# Change validation message in MVC at runtime

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I have a validation message for where I need to change the error message text at run time (when they click the submit button).

Based on what the id is passed in, the user has to send XML or a Query.

If they should send in a query, I want it to say: "The Query is required."

If they should send in xml, I want it to say: "The XML is required."

I've tried to clear the ModelState.Clear();

I've tried to NOT set the second parameter in ValidationMessageFor()... (usually it is "", but when I try to set it within there, then it automatically shows on the page when the page loads)

```
        @Html.ValidationMessage("RawXmlOrQueryText", string.Format("The {0} field is required.", Model.Label), new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

if I do something like this, then it never shows period:

```
 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.RawXmlOrQueryText, string.Format("The {0} field is required.", Model.Label), new { @class = "text-danger", style = "display:" + "none" + ";" })
```

Is there a better way to do this?

I want to be able to set the error message at run time and it to now show on the page until the user clicks the button.

Answer (score 0):

Are you ok with using [AddModelError()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.modelbinding.modelstatedictionary.addmodelerror?view=aspnetcore-2.2)?

Assuming you are using this model:

```
public class IndexModel
{
    public string QueryText { get; set; }
}
```

In your post method, add the following code:

```
var isXML = true; //oversimplification of your validation code
var someErrorMsg = isXML ? "The XML is required." : "The Query is required.";
ModelState.AddModelError(nameof(model.QueryText), someErrorMsg);
return View(model);
```

Comment: this works, but it still displays on initial load. Am I missing a property to turn that off on load? I only want it to fire IF they go to click the submit button.

Comment: So for now, unless someone can tell me otherwise, I will just do the following:         [Required(ErrorMessage = "Text is required.")] AND not allow the validation message to be dynamic :-(

Comment: If you are passing the model on the get method, you need to remove the Required validation annotation on that property and resort to validation in the controller instead, or dont pass the model on the get method at all, unless something prevents you from doing this.